# LwIP mDNS does not support SUBTYPE

Tags: dns, lwip, mdns, dns-sd

I'm using the mDNS protocol implementation on lWIP, I need to add **subtype** for an mDNS service i'v created, but there is not any function or macro that could be used to set the subtype of a service. (thing existes in the standards and many other mDNS implementations on linux), **Does anyone have an idea or the same issue before ?**
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After some researchs in the mdns and dns-sd standards with a light understanding of your mDNS implementation, i found a solution to implement it, actually it should be added as PTR RR answer to mdns output packet.
I tested it many times and it works perfectly, So that resolve my problem.
Here is a pull request i'v done in the Github LwIP repository :
https://github.com/lwip-tcpip/lwip/pull/7
Otherwise you can check the patch based on the master branch in the link bellow :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wvge-EXT7tWr5M7phGl7sfhy_wtR8U1K?usp=sharing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).